# SSRS URL acces pass DDMMYY dateformat

Tags: ssrs-2012

How can I pass a date/time parameter to my report via url. I only have access to the DDMMYY format of the date. I know I should tell SSRS what language to use with the

rs:ParameterLanguage=de-DE

But I dont know what language DDMMYY is.

```
   http://<>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/<>/<>/report&para1=801&para2=1000011&DATE=070415&rs:ParameterLanguage=???
```

Answer (score 0):

Oké, I guess this is not possible, but I added a hidden text parameter to the report so I could convert is with custom vbscript. and let the query decide what to use as the date parameter.